# Solving the system $2^x3^y=5$, $2^y3^x=7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the system: \begin{cases}2^x\times 3^y=5\\
> 2^y\times 3^x=7\end{cases}

My attempt.

$$2^x=\frac {5}{3^y}$$

$$x=\log_2{\frac {5}{3^y}}$$

$$2^y\times 3^{\log_2{\frac {5}{3^y}}}=7$$

I'm stuck here.  What should I do now?

Comment: Try expanding $\log(5/3^y)=\log(5)-y\log(3)$. Now you have something like $a^y b^{c y+d}=7$

Comment: Hint: Try multiplying and dividing the equations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $2^x3^y=5$ is linear. Namely, taking the natural log, this equation is equivalent to

$$\ln(2)x+\ln(3)y=\ln(5).$$

If the natural log is confusion, taking the logarithm with any base and you'll still get the right answer. The equation $2^y3^x=7$ becomes

$$\ln(2)y+\ln(3)x=\ln(7).$$

This problem thus just solving a system of linear equations. The logarithm is an amazing "linearization" tool in mathematics, since it changes problems about multiplication (like the system you were given) into problems about addition (like the linear system we got). Hopefully from this point solving the problem is not too difficult!

Answer (score 1):

***HINT***

$2^x 3^y=5\Rightarrow\ln(2^x 3^y)=\ln5\Rightarrow\ln2^x+\ln3^y=\ln5\Rightarrow $ $$x\ln2+y\ln3=\ln5$$

Similarly, work with $2^y 3^x=7$ to obtain $$x\ln3+y\ln2=\ln7$$

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

Divide the two original equations:

$2^{x-y}3^{-(x-y)} = \frac 57$

$(\frac 23)^{x-y} =  \frac 57$

$x-y = \frac{ln \frac 57}{\ln \frac 23}$

Similarly, multiply the two original equations to get:

$x+y = \frac{\ln 35}{\ln 6}$

Now just solve the simple linear simultaneous equations and use the laws of logs to simplify the end result for an exact answer (or a calculator if you just need an approximate one).